# Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with a table called users and a field called name. I have the following HTML code:

```
 <form action="change.php?link=edit" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="lg" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Save changes">
    </form>
```

And this PHP code, that updates the name field with what the user writes in the input:

```
  if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
       $name= $_POST['name'];
       $id=$_SESSION['id'];
       $sql = "UPDATE users SET name=:name WHERE id=$id";
       $sql->bindParam(":name", $name);
       $consulta = $db->prepare($sql);
       $result = $consulta->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

That code gives me the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string", however, if I change the PHP code to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id";
```

And commenting the line:

```
//$sql->bindParam(":name", $name);
```

I get no errors. However I know that's a bad programming practice since that code is vulnerable to sql injection. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the single quotes arount `':name'`.  The system already knows it is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change :

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name=:name WHERE id=$id";
$sql->bindParam(":name", $name);
$consulta = $db->prepare($sql);
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name=:name WHERE id=:id";
$consulta = $db->prepare($sql);
$consulta->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting error message.  You should be able to fix it by removing the single quotes:

```
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET name = :name WHERE id = :id";
```

PHP/SQL already knows the types of the parameters.  The single quotes are unnecessary.

Note:  You should make `:id` a parameter as well.

Comment: Thank you, I've already removed them, but I keep getting the same error.